# How to Stop Android emulator when it appears to both running and offline?

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, android-emulator

I tried to run my android emulator but it froze at the Google Start screen and then crashed showing the emulator with a black box around it. I am unable to re-run the emulator because it says the emulator is already running.

[Emulator stuck at Google Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6L5E.png)

[Emulator Screen with Black Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7idu.png)

[Error when I try to close the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70pmP.png)

[Error when I try to Re-run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjonX.png)

[Error when I select the "emulator-5554"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tryqK.png)

I also try to stop, wipe or delete the emulator from the AVD manager it says I am unable to because it is already running.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: Your 'android' emulator looks like a iPhone. Aside from that, I would recommend you to use GenyMotion. To stop the current emulator, open CMD and type "adb kill-server" and open task manager and find "adb" in processes and end the process tree. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is for emulators running on a windows operating system.

Open the task manager and search for the following process
[image]

**Name might vary depending on the emulator you are running**

And just end task. 
You should be able to wipe data off the emulator from android studio. If not, try restarting android studio. 
Hope this solves your problem.
Regards.

Comment: I am unable to end the qemu-system-x86_64.exe task

Comment: @emansyl open your cmd with admin privileges, and user the following command, `tasklist`, it will list all the tasks, with their PID, then run `Taskkill /PID (enter here pid of your process) /F`

Comment: This is weird, I can see the process in the tasklist but when I'm trying to kill the process with Id it says: 
ERROR: The process with PID XXXXX could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.